# jQuery dialog jumps on background ajax control update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

We have a silverlight control inside jQuery modal dialog, to upload files. When files are uploaded, the page in background gets the update and refreshes the activity part of the page (e.g. $("#activity").html(dataFromServer)).

However when that part of the page is refreshed, the dialog jumps to top/bottom, on every refresh. This happens in both IE8 and Chrome. jQuery 1.4.4.

Are there any bugs in jQuery or what is happening?

UPD: Seem to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467102/dialog-box-not-positions-center-screen/1469208#1469208) (page content change -> scroll params (not position but...) changes -> dialog position changed) but I'm not sure. And still wonder how to fix without manual hacks in ajax events.

And, actually, I can fix the issue with

```
           $('my-selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

after .html(data) BUT the dialog jumps to top then back, which is still ugly.

Comment: The modal stays open and the page in the background bounces to the top/bottom?

Comment: No. The page is always at the top, it doesn't scroll. The dialog bounces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, ui.position was not included in the custom build (done not by me to give an excuse).