# jQuery UI Dialog not Centered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery and I am loading content into a div, then displaying it as a dialog. However, it is not centering the dialog.

Does anyone have a solution?

Code:

```
function Core_Load_Register()
{
    $("body").append("<div id='Register_Popup'></div>");
    $("#Register_Popup").load("index.php?section=FrontPage&page=Register&nogui=true");
    $("#Register_Popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        buttons: 
        {
            "Register New Account":
            function() 
            {
                
            },
            
            "Cancel":
            function()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Example Screenshot:

[image: jQuery Dialog not Centered Example]

Comment: try doing this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467102/dialog-box-not-positions-center-screen

Comment: Tried but didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure where your dialog code sits in your DOM, but I would try putting it as the last element before `</body>`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I updated jQuery UI to the latest version and it magically fixed itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your content is dynamic try waiting for the load command to finish first.

```
$("#Register_Popup")
  .load("index.php?section=FrontPage&page=Register&nogui=true", 
  function()
  {
    $("#Register_Popup").dialog({ 
      modal: true, 
      height: "auto", 
      width: "auto", 
      buttons:  
      { 
        "Register New Account": 
        function()  
        { 

        }, 

        "Cancel": 
        function() 
        { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
      } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: The position is centered by default. But even so, I tried defining it and it still didn't work. The issue is I am loading content which puts it off center.

Comment: Updated Answer per your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using specific numeric values rather than the 'auto' height and width option works a lot better and always centers.

This isn't always optimal, especially when using dynamic data in the dialog.. but it worked for me (using jquery ui 1.9.2).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was similar to the accepted answer.  Content was not dynamic in the sense of it being an AJAX call, rather the `src` of an image tag was assigned immediately before showing the dialog.  Even with fixed width and height on the dialog it would fail to center.

```
setTimeout(function() {
            img.dialog({
                draggable: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                maxHeight: '768',
                maxWidth: '1024',
                modal: true
            });
        }, 500 );
```

By giving it a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) it seems the dialog was able to be aware of its content and position itself correctly.